# Google Account Log in doesn't work on LTE/Data

Tags: google, google-account

Note I am using Android ver. 5.0.2 OnePlus One Cyanogen OS 12.0-YNG1TAS2I3

When I am on Wifi my device has no problem signing into my Google Account. 
But when I am on Data/LTE my google account has log in issues.

For instance:
YOUTUBE APP: If I am logged in, I get a "Network Connection Error" even though my internet works fine. If I log out of the Youtube app by clearing the app data I can watch videos again, but trying to log into my google account gets me the Network Connection error again and does not allow the log in.
I can however open the web browser, go to youtube.com, log in, and access my youtube content.

GOOGLE MAPS APP: On LTE I can view all my starred locations on Google Maps, but when I try and add a new starred location it tells me to select my google account. When I select it nothing happens.

Google Now sometimes works, but sometimes shows the network connection error.

POKEMON GO: Trying to log into Pokemon GO via Google Account on LTE fails, but works on WiFi.

Not sure if relevant: It's my first time having cellphone with data plan. Also currently in Japan.

Comment: Try disabling "sync only with WiFi" setting.

Comment: Where can I find this setting? The only one I can find is for backing up google photos via WiFi only.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem: [Cannot log in to google account when on data (works on Wifi)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/151905/cannot-log-in-to-google-account-when-on-data-works-on-wifi/151907#151907)

After contacting both google and my network provider, it was clear that the problem is on the device. For me there was a built-in security app from Lenovo, blocking 'google services'.

Check all your firewalls, antivirus programs and the settings>data that nothing as googleservices or googleframework is blocked. Uncheck 'restrict background data' in case it is enabled for all apps or google-specific. Also allow syncing data for apps while on data ofcourse.

Comment: Thank you, I did have Google Services specifically restricted to not use background data. However it has used up 2 GB in background data already this month, so I'll probably end up toggling it off frequently... I probably disabled it to stop OTA updates from downloading constantly over data.