# Cannot log in to google account when on data (works on Wifi)

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, google-account, mobile-network, wlan

Device: Lenovo A806 with Android 4.4.2

Problem: Cannot log in to google account while on data (**works on wifi**)

Description: 
Cannot open google play (connection failed, retry) or add a new google account to the android settings (signing in, may take minutes). Also cannot eg log in to PokemonGO with google account while on data, but can log in with non-google account. The game keeps playing if later I go off-wifi. Wifi is required only for sign in. If I disconnect and allow some time to pass then cannot log in again on data.

Tried:

1. Date and time settings are automatic and I verified that the difference to atomic clock is under 1s.
2. Different SIM in different country has the same problem (network operator-independent)
3. Cannot add new google account (account independent, not related to 2-step verification or wrong password etc)
4. Hosts file contains only 127.0.0.1 localhost.
5. Uninstalling/Reinstalling, clearing cache, clearing data, forcing to stop the app and restarting does not seem to help because more than one app have the same problem.
6. Captured the HTTP/S traffic using Drony but didn't manage to understand which is the call to the google account, and see its status.

I know the question may seem a duplicate, but I haven't found any solved question about having this problem ONLY on data (wifi works so that rules out many solutions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have background data restricted? Usually I can't login to my Google account with background data restricted. Try with removing background restriction.

Comment: There is no general background data restriction option on the above mobile/android configuration. If I authenticate on wifi, I can continue on data without problem.

Comment: Then maybe your Google play services has no access to mobile data. See if providing the necessary permissions for Google play services to access mobile data works

Comment: I think it got fixed, it was probably something similar: The mobile data access was available for google services in android settings but there is a built-in lenovo app called 'security' which has a submodule called 'firewall', and this was blocking google services when on data to save on MB usage.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem in LE 1s, So,I have done  system settings-->dual sim and mobile networks-->data management-->connection control-->select app that you want in mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] by Patroklos A Jul 25 '16 at 15:39

I think it got fixed, it was probably something similar: The mobile data access was available for google services in android settings but there is a built-in lenovo app called 'security' which has a submodule called 'firewall', and this was blocking google services when on data to save on MB usage. Thank you –

go to settings > security > apps with usage access > google play services > click on 'i' icon > data usage > uncheck restrict background data

you can also access it from settings > apps > google play services > data usage > uncheck restrict background data

Done! Thanks for the clue, Patroklos!

Answer (score 0):

When I installed my phone for the first time, I probably restricted too many apps from using mobile data.

I have system apps called 'msa' and "Browser services". When I turned mobile data for both apps back on, I finally was able to log into my Google account again via a mobile data connection. ':-D